# Mongodbd login with Mongoose to new database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoDB in Atlas cloud but now I want to movie to a local database. I installed MongoDB and created a admin user. Now I connect with mongoose to :

```
mongodb://login:pass@db.myserver.com:27017/admin
```

Works well. Now I create a new development database "develop".
I try to connect

```
mongodb://login:pass@db.myserver.com:27017/develop
```

This failed to login. OK, I understand that the admin database is the "/admin" one and that user is authenticated to this database but I thought that an admin can access all databases in a mongodb server?
In Atlas I just created the develop database and connected to it without any problem.

How I can well connect with mongoose to the new develop database? Do I need to create a second admin for this database?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that I have to name the auth database in my connection string.

```
mongodb://login:pass@db.myserver.com:27017/develop?authSource=admin
```